# How can I initialize a mixin's immutable data in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, mixins, final

I am programming in Flutter using Dart 2.1.0, and come across this situation:

```
mixin Salt {
  final int pinches;  // Immutable, and I want to delay initialization.

  // Cannot declare constructors for mixin
}

class Meat with Salt {
  Meat(int pinches) ... // How to initialize it?
}
```

`Salt` has no constructor, so I cannot use initializer list. `pinches` is `final`, so I cannot set it in `Meat`'s constructor.

I don't want to make `Salt` a class because `Meat` may need to extend from something else.

And I want to keep `pinches` immutable.

Any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48):

You can change the declaration of your mixin to:

```
mixin Salt {
  int get pitches;
}
```

And then define the field inside the implementation class

```
class Meat with Salt {
  final int pitches;
  Meat(this.pitches);
}
```

Comment: What point of using `mixin` in this situation, If we should duplicate code this way?

Comment: Mixins are not for declaring variables. But for reusable methods instead

Comment: @RémiRousselet how can I initialize on Flutter? `DemiLogic` is mixin

`class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> with DemoLogic {
`

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, but `final int pitches` should be annotated with `@override`.
Also the property in the `mixin` could be declared as `abstract final int pitches` instead of getter. Totally just flavour but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 8):

I offer my take on a solution to this.  By marking the variable `late` you can make it `final`.  No warning will appear if you fail to initialize it so use with caution.

```dart
mixin Salt {
  late final int pinches;
}

class Vegetable with Salt {
  Vegetable(int pinches) {
    this.pinches = pinches;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By design it is not possible to declare a final member into a mixin because it is not possible to declare a constructor for initializing the final member, 
citing [the docs](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/mixins#syntax-and-semantics):

> However, in this proposal, a mixin may only be extracted from a class that has no declared constructors. This restriction avoids complications that arise due to the need to pass constructor parameters up the inheritance chain.

A compromise may be to declare a private member and implement only a getter.
`_pinches` is visible only inside the library, it is read-only for library users.

```
mixin Salt {
  int _pinches;

  get pinches => _pinches;

}

class Meat with Salt {

  Meat(int pinches)  {
   _pinches = pinches;
  }
}
```

**Note**: the above pattern, because of the visibility rules, works only if the mixin and the mixed classes reside in the same library.

Comment: That only works if `Salt` and `Meat` are declared in the same library, otherwise `_pinches` would not be accessible.

Comment: Can I half-accept two answers, because @attdona and @RémiRousselet together give the whole picture? @RémiRousselet 's suggestion would work, but it defeats the purpose of having data in mixins. And `_pinches` is not strictly immutable in @attdona 's suggestion. You together confirm that there's no ideal solution. I have up-voted both answers, but am sorry for not (fully) accepting either.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to attdona's suggestion, but a little bit closer to what you really wanted, you could do it like

```dart
mixin Salt {
  int _pinches;
  int get pinches => _pinches;
  void initSalt(int pinches) {
    assert(_pinches == null);
    _pinches = pinches;
  }
}

class Meat with Salt {
  Meat(int pinches) {
    initSalt(pinches);
  }
}
```

It's still not strictly final, but (so long as the mixin's in a different library so you can't change the private member directly) it's immutable at runtime. Not as good as if it could be properly final, but maybe close enough.

Answer (score 2):

The following method allows you to set the data at a later time, and gets rid of the warning:

`This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final`

```
mixin Salt {
  final SaltData _saltData = SaltData();

  int get pinches => _saltData.pinches;

  set pinches(int extraData) {
    _saltData.pinches = extraData;
  }
}

class SaltData {
  int pinches = 0;
}
```

So what I did is create a class `SaltData`. This will store all the variables you need.

The private `_saltData` variable is final, this will stop the warning.

Then use a getter and setter to retrieve and update the data.

```
int get pinches => _saltData.pinches;

set pinches(int extraData) {
  _saltData.pinches = extraData;
}
```

If you want you can could expose the entire saltData object as well:

`SaltData get saltData => _saltData;`